# Renaming to values in columns using r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that has unclean data(so typical right). So I am trying to rename them to common values. So all which are like `SF` or `Bay Area` or `San Francisco` should be `San Francisco`. Similarly for `New York` as well. How can I do that? Below is how my data looks like

```
datapasta::dpasta(df)
c("US", "US", "SF", "NYC", "LA", "BOS", "San Francisco", "NYC", "LA", "BOS", "Bay Area", "NYC", "LA", "BOS", "SF", "SFO", "LA", "BOS", "SF", "SF", "SF", "SF", "SF", "New York", "NYC", "NYC", "NYC", "NYC", "Boston", "BOS")
```

Comment: Try `recode` in dplyr - https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/recode.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case_when` for this:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- c("US", "US", "SF", "NYC", "LA", "BOS", "San Francisco", "NYC", "LA", "BOS", "Bay Area", "NYC", "LA", "BOS", "SF", "SFO", "LA", "BOS", "SF", "SF", "SF", "SF", "SF", "New York", "NYC", "NYC", "NYC", "NYC", "Boston", "BOS")

df <- case_when(
  df %in% c("SF", "Bay Area") ~ "San Francisco",
  df %in% c("NYC") ~ "New York",
  TRUE ~ df
)
```